# Updating intersection tables, alternative to delete->insert

Tags: mysql, sql, database, intersection

I hope some one more SQL wise can help me. Suppose the following table and relationships they're compacted.

```
orders(PK_refno,customer, status)
order_accessories(PK_refno,PK_acc)
accessories(PK_acc,name,desc)
```

As you can see this is a typical `1:*----*:*----*:1` scenario the the issue or my concern is when updating, as the accessories that each order has can be modified, meaning that an user can add/remove accessories.

The only way I've thought to do it by using MySQL is to delete all accessories and then insert the updated ones.

**I dislike it this way.** As I think that probably there's a SQL way to do it. Maybe someone can suggest and advanced query (which I'll study of course)

The other way I thought was to:

Retrieve the originals.

Compare them and remove/add the differences.

I'm not a fan of this either because it would be done in the app, not in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say the table starts like this.

```
order_accessories
PK_refno  PK_acc
1         73
1         74
1         75
1         86
1         92
```

Let's also say that 75 is supposed to be 76. Assuming a sane user interface, the user can just change 75 to 76. A sane user interface would send this statement to the dbms.

```
update order_accessories
set PK_acc = 76
where (PK_refno = 1 and PK_acc = 75);
```

If 75 were not supposed to be there in the first place, then the user would just delete that one row. A sane user interface would send this statement to the dbms.

```
delete from order_accessories
where (PK_refno = 1 and PK_acc = 75);
```

Comment: But doesn't updating a record where the condition is going to be changed (PK_acc = 75 to PK_acc =76) cause trouble?

Comment: @Triztian: It doesn't cause any trouble at the database level. It could cause trouble at the user interface level if your UI programmer isn't competent.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add that I went for first deleting all of the records that matched the order to be updated and then re-inserted the new ones.